# how to install jdk in ubuntu without an internet

Tags: ubuntu, java

Right now I don't have a working internet connection on my Ubuntu 12.10 .
So is there a way to download some kinda archive or debian package and copy it to my Ubuntu and then install it ?

Comment: Have you tried this: [Ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1773421)? First result of when you use google.

Answer (score 1):

You can download oracle jdk from their wesite and install it in your ubuntu machine without internet connection

Answer (score 0):

You can install most any .deb or package if you can get it on the machine.